# Tool for Comparing/Viewing Classes composing the architecture of WPF

Tags: wpf, class, architecture, implementation, msdn

Is there any tool, given any two classes, that will give me the difference in properties and methods between them (also is there any way to view the implementation, because if I could view the implementation I could probably write a parsing program to get the differences).

For example: I have Visual and Drawing which derives from Visual, I want to see all the properties and methods that Drawing adds. Right now I am doing this manually on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Base-class-sub-class relationships you normally can easily use VisualStudio to see what new properties are added in the sub-class, just right click the class-name somewhere in code and select `Go To Definition`. Additionally there is the `Class View` window (can be found in the `View` menu) which also nicely lists everything about a class. The `Object Browser` (`View > Other Windows`) provides similar functionality.

Comment: cool, I didn't know about the right click go to definition. thanks. I could probably use `diff` to get the new properties, or go from there to do something useful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any, but somewhere like [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/) might have something.

I wanted something similar a while back and ended up building my own tool, that used [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719979%28VS.71%29.aspx). If you don't know much about reflection then it's a really good way to get yourself an introduction, and it makes for a fun programming project for a long week-end or rainy day (not that my wife would probably agree).

Comment: thanks, I've heard about reflection, but I am not familiar, probably would be a good project.